# Truffle Dapp Development

Tags: go-ethereum, dapp-development, testnets, truffle

Is there anybody who has developed the Dapp using truffle framework and ethereum testnet ? I am getting some alien errors and i am not getting the solution on internet.So i need a person who has done it start to end? Your help will be precious to me.

Comment: Don't ask to ask - just ask your question, with as much detail as possible (relevant parts of your code, simplified if possible, and the error you're getting, at a minimum).

Comment: i have asked a question three times but nobody doesn't even understand my question from TRUFFLE point  of view. So this was all i can do.@Nick Johnson

Comment: We certainly can't understand your question if you don't ask it. As it is, your question isn't one - if you want an answer, you need to describe the problem you're having.

Comment: I am trying to develop two communicating Dapps. I have designed both as different module of a contract execution. On one Dapp, i deployed a contract and on the second one i only compiled the contract. On first Dapp everything is fine, but on the second one, i am not able to access the functions of the deployed contract.( Consider go-ethereum testnet) @NickJohnson

Comment: You need to put that in your question, with the source for the contracts - reduced to the minimal example that still shows the problem - and as much detail about what happens as you can.